# Jquery JSON multiple requests

Tags: jquery, json, api

I need to adjust the following code to make multiple requests for 3 separate pages (adjusting &page=1, &page=2, &page=3), other than repeating it 3 times how can I combine this?

```
$.getJSON("http://www.behance.net/v2/users/" + user + "/projects?api_key=" + api + "&callback=?&page=1", function (data) {
    var project_str = "";
    for (i = 0; i < data.projects.length; i++) {
        obj = {};
        obj = data.projects[i];
        project_str += '<a class="link" href="#' + obj.id + '"><img src="' + obj.covers['404'] + '" /></a>';
    }
    $('#behance_container div').append(project_str);
});
```

Comment: seems foolish to expose your api key... would be smarter to store it on your server , send pages wanted to server and have it make all the requests and return one JSON response for all pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
for(var i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
    $.getJSON("http://www.behance.net/v2/users/" + user + "/projects?api_key=" + api + "&callback=?&page=" + i, function (data) {
        var project_str = "";
        for (i = 0; i < data.projects.length; i++) {
            obj = {};
            obj = data.projects[i];
            project_str += '<a class="link" href="#' + obj.id + '"><img src="' + obj.covers['404'] + '" /></a>';
        }
        $('#behance_container div').append(project_str);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each([1,2,3], function(i, numb) {
    $.getJSON("http://www.behance.net/v2/users/"+user+"/projects?api_key="+api+"&callback=?&page="+numb, function (data) {
        var project_str = "";
        $.each(data.projects, function(i, obj) {
            project_str += '<a class="link" href="#' + obj.id + '"><img src="' + obj.covers['404'] + '" /></a>';
        });
        $('#behance_container div').append(project_str);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `$.getJSON` call is async, you might want to collect all the data first before showing it to the user. Otherwise, you'll get a little "flash" each time data is retrieved/appended to the DOM. The following is untested, but should work (if not, I hope you helped you in the right direction).

```
var nrOfPages = 3,
    projects = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= nrOfPages; i++) {
    retrieveData(i);
}

// Retrieve the data by the pageNr
function retrieveData(pageNr) {
    $.getJSON("http://www.behance.net/v2/users/" + user + "/projects?api_key=" + api + "&callback=?&page=" + pageNr, function (data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.projects.length; i++) {
            projects.push(data.projects[i]);
        };

        if(pageNr == nrOfPages) { // Check if all the pages are retrieved
            processData();
        }
    });
};

// Process the retrieved data
function processData() {
    var project_str = "";
    for (i = 0; i < data.projects.length; i++) {
        obj = {};
        obj = data.projects[i];
        project_str += '<a class="link" href="#' + obj.id + '"><img src="' + obj.covers['404'] + '" /></a>';
    }
    $('#behance_container div').append(project_str);
};
```